# How do I set a HTTP header for a request with wreq?

Tags: haskell, wreq

I see there is a likely function to do this of `getWith` which passes an `Option` value.

However looking up `Option` type seems to show something with very little info in haddock: [image]

How can I set these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wreq uses lenses hence it can be done using the below:

```
let opts = defaults
           & header "Content-Type" .~ ["application/json"]
getWith opts "http://localhost"
```